# MY SMTP mail keeps coming through as Junk

Tags: php, html, smtp

I know this is plastered all over the net... But i've tried a lot of solutions and it just wont seem to work. My SMTP mail first came through as junk, and now just comes into my inbox, but with a warning notice saying the email didnt pass the fraud tests..

So im using Optus's SMTP server (mail.optusnet.com.au), and for the "sendmail_from" i have my email address..

for the actual mail, i have this:

```
$message = 'Hello, $user;

$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'Welcome';
$headers = 'From: myemail@hotmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: myemail@hotmail.com' . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail('myemail@hotmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Any ideas guys?

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: Have you tried sending to different domains? Chances are your mail is seen as "fraudulent" because hotmail's ``spf records`` do not correspond to Optus' mail server. Furthermore, hotmail is generally seen as an unsafe origin by some spam filters. Most likely a combination of these 2 will have raised a few flags.

Comment: Thats what i dont get.. when i left it as the default "yourmail@yourdomain.com" it went straight to inbox and didnt worry about anything.. 

FYI, "myemail" is just a placeholder.. i actually use my personal email but edited it out for the sake of this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of E-Mail providers check every received email  to decide whether it's a spam or not. For example , if you send an email as `myemail@hotmail.com`  from `mail.optusnet.com.au` , it will not pass the test and will be put under junk category. In my experience, Yahoo! and Hotmail usually put every email with `X-Mailer: PHP` header as junk!

For more information take a look at [Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

---

About comment:
If you take a look at your received email, you will see something like this:

```
Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: x.x.x.x is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of email@mail.optusnet.com.au) client-ip=x.x.x.x;
```

it tells client that this email at least is **NOT**  trying to show itself as someone else, so it goes to your inbox. but If you use `something@hotmail.com`, since `hotmail.com` has a valid IP and it's different from `mail.optusnet.com.au`, so it goes to your junk folder.

Comment: Check the comment i left under my question

Comment: Okay, so how do i stop it from showing up as a fraudulent message?

Comment: Use an email like `myemail@mail.optusnet.com.au`!

Comment: Hmm... so i actually have to sign up for an optus email, and cant just put that in the send from fields?

Comment: I you're using `mail.optusnet.com.au` as mail server, you don't have to sign up. By the way, if your mail server is marked as spam sender, you have to change your server!