# php mail not sending to outlook.com

Tags: php, email, outlook, outlook.com

my contact form is not sending emails to outlook.com
i have tested it on other email accounts and works just fine.
is there anything i can do to solve that issue?

my php code is the following

```
<?php 
$to = 'xxx@xxx.gr';
$headers = 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){

$subject1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
$mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
$subject = " $subject1 $mail";


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);





header("location: contact.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Outlook is hypersensitive about spam. Make sure you use SPF and/or DKIM, as well as ensuring you have the correct reverse DNS set up.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18870380/440546) may help!

Comment: You have no `From:` header for instance. That alone is a sure-fire way of it not being accepted into their system and automatically gets thrown out/ignored. So, it figures *"I don't know where this came from, therefore I'm not accepting this request".* Plus I would change this `$subject = " $subject1 $mail";` to something else if I were you.

Comment: @AlexandrosTseros Are you gonna tell every user to do the same? i don't think so, not a useful solution.

Comment: It is not, you are right. It was just a "trick" to get it working. PHPmailer solves the issue definitely. @DannyG